# How to solve this error in blockchain and PHP

Tags: php, laravel, blockchain, bitcoin

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://chain.so/api/get_address_balance/BTCTEST/undefined' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are facing CORS Origin issue then you can use this package

```
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Comment: How to solve this error GET https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/BTCTEST/undefined 404

Comment: why you are sending `undefined` in url. I think there should be sine value.